# Saving data directly to the localStorage from axios response in Electron-Vue application

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, electron, axios

I am trying to save some data to the localStorage in Electron application, based on Vue.js using axios like this:

```
mounted () {
    axios.get(myURLhere).then(response => {
        let data = response.data
        data[anotherThing] = someElseDataHere
        this.localStorage['data'] = JSON.stringify(data)
    })
}
```

In "then"-block data variable is correct. But in localStorage data = some empty Observer object!

What am I doing wrong? Is "then"-block not enough to wait until data will come to store in localStorage? And in this case how can I wait for it in my code?

Comment: `localStorage` is a global object. Have you purposefully defined a `localStorage` property of your Vue (you are using `this.localStorage`)?

Comment: Yes, I did. LocalStorage (this.localStorage) works good. The problem is somewere in axios processing of fetch request. Because localStorage works fine in other cases.

Comment: If you want to save it directly to localStorage, use window.localStorage, not the this.localStorage. Or? Am I missing something?

Comment: I think there's no difference... Because ALL OTHER ACTIONS WITH LOCALSTORAGE ARE OK. I do all the interactions with localStorage through "this." and it works. And in this case it works too. But not correct. Because the value is not null, it's an object of Observer type. But the Observer is empty. It means that the code processed before the Observer will get data from server.
LocalStorage takes Observer as a value. But I need to store an Object with responded data, not empty Promise, that still waiting for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use vue-localStorage. For some reason it don't do an Array-to-string conversion right:

```
this.$localStorage.set('data', data) // data will be not an Array, but an Observer instance
```

This is why I had Object instances stored right, but an error with Arrays. So to fix it you need to work with localStorage directly, like this:

```
localStorage['data'] = JSON.stringify(data)
```

People, who told me to check localStorage were partly right - the problem was in localStorage yet.